# Android Wear Geofencing Sample App

Tags: android, wear-os, geofencing

have anyone implement the sample app for geofencing wear form google? i changed the latitude & longitude values and get a WearableClientImpl.onPostInitHandler: done but my samsung wear dont get message any ideas?

If a Start the sample appp on my device the service started and get the current locationn but no data communication between my app and the wear ! whats wrong? my wear app dont get  the notificaton from my app ,,

Comment: A little more explanation of your issue would really help us to help you - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Geofencing sample that is included with the API 20 SDK samples, these are downloaded by the SDK Manager, and will be present in your Android Studio SDK directory, like this on OSX:

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/samples/android-20/wearable/Geofencing/
```

Replace /Applications/Android\ Studio.app with the location on your Windows machine in C:\Program Files or on your Linux machine.